# Retrieving Google Analytics tracking code automatically from OAUTH login

Tags: google-analytics, oauth-2.0

If my system has OAUTH access to my Google account, can it use that to automatically pull a tracking token for a domain I control from Google, or do I have to log in and copy paste?

Answer (score 0):

Inasfar as you are asking if you can create Google Analytics accounts via the [management api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert), no. However you can create a property in an existing account via the api and the response will include the property id. [Follow the link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) for documentation.

Comment: Just to clarify: say I have a Google account that is enabled for Analytics. I want to automate adding domains I control to that account, by creating tracking tokens linked to my existing account. I think that's what you're saying I can do, but I just want to check. Is it? :)